# Pagination by year with URL segments in ExpressionEngine

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm trying to display pages of channel entries by year, but if the year (segment_4) is absent I want to display all the results, 10 per page.

The problem is  results older than the first year won't show because of an issue with segment_4 as I have it setup now. The "Next Page" link includes "P10" as segment_4, which breaks the logic I have set-up.

Could anyone recommend a technique where you can display channel entries by year using URLsegments, but show all years without.

Tag that runs when there is no segment_4:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="communications" limit="10" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}
```

Tag that runs when there is a segment_4:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="communications" limit="10" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" year="{segment_4}" month="{segment_5}"}
```

Comment: I don't know expression engine but when I run into this in CI I would just set segment 4 to 0 as default then check if it is anything other than 0 for the tag to run.

Comment: Makes sense. I don't think there is any native way in EE to match any kind of expression like if variable starts with "P" do this.

Comment: How about setting segment 4 to P1 as default and run your years off segment 5 would that work?

Comment: Yes -- I think if I abandoned my URL structure and made years (5) and months (6) I could use P1 as (4). Worth a shot!

Comment: Thanks you. So this works well, the only issue now is the `{auto_path}` tag used for Next Page links as it says "C5/2011/P10" instead of the desired "C5/P10/2011". Trying make this path manually or something to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two addons that may help you with that. Switchee, in addition to being a great case logic add on also gives you regex through which you could detect pagination. The other you might have a look at it Mo Variables, which has an "if pagination" conditional also for detecting the pagination segment in your URL. Both are available on devot-ee.com